# Select statement returns data although given value in the where clause is false

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a table on my `MySQL` db named `membertable`. The table consists of two fields which are `memberid` and `membername`. The `memberid` field has the type of `integer` and uses auto_increment function starting from `2001`. The `membername` table has the type of `varchar`.

The `membertable` has two records with the same order as described above. The records look like this :

memberid   : 2001
membername : john smith

memberid   : 2002
membername : will smith

I found something weird when I ran a `SELECT` statement against the `memberid` field. Running the following statement :

```
SELECT * FROM `membertable` WHERE `memberid` = '2001somecharacter'
```

It returned the first data.

Why did that happen? There's no record with `memberid` = `2001somecharacter`. It looks like MySQL only search the first 4 character (2001) and when It's found related data, which is the returned data above, it denies the remaining characters.

How could this happen? And is there any way to turn off this behavior?

--

`membertable` uses `innodb` engine

Comment: Could you make a [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com) demonstrating this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because mysql tries to convert "2001somecharacter" into a number which returns 2001.

Since you're comparing a number to a string, you should use

```
SELECT * FROM `membertable` WHERE CONVERT(`memberid`,CHAR) = '2001somecharacter';
```

to avoid this behavior.

OR to do it properly, is NOT put your search variable in quotes so that it has to be a number otherwise it'll blow up because of syntax error and then in front end making sure it's a number before passing in the query.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/295267/16)

Answer (score 0):

Your finding is an expexted MySQL behaviour.
MySQL converts a varchar to an integer starting from the beginning. As long as there are numeric characters wich can easily be converted, they are icluded in the conversion process. If there's a letter, the conversion stops returning the integer value of the numeric string read so far...

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html)'s some description of this behavior on the MySQL documentation Site. Unfortunately, it's not mentioned directly in the text, but there's an example which exactly shows this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is very liberal in converting string values to numeric values when evaluated in numeric context.

As a demonstration, adding 0 causes the string to evaluated in a numeric context:

```
SELECT '2001foo' + 0   --> 2001 
     , '01.2-3E' + 0   --> 1.2
     , 'abc567g' + 0   --> 0
```

When a string is evaluated in a numeric context, MySQL reads the string character by character, until it encounters a character where the string can no longer be interpreted as a numeric value, or until it reaches the end of the string.

I don't know of a way to "turn off" or disable this behavior. (There may be a setting of sql_mode that changes this behavior, but likely that change will impact other SQL statements that are working, which may stop working if that change is made.

Typically, this kind of check of the arguments is done in the application.

But if you need to do this in the SELECT statement, one option would be cast/convert the column as a character string, and then do the comparison.

But that can have some significant performance consequences. If we do a cast or convert (or any function) on a column that's in a condition in the WHERE clause, MySQL will not be able to use a range scan operation on a suitable index. We're forcing MySQL to perform the cast/convert operation  on *every* row in the table, and compare the result to the literal.

So, that's not the best pattern.

If I needed to perform a check like that within the SQL statement, I would do something like this:

```
  WHERE t.memberid = '2001foo' + 0 
    AND CAST('2001foo' + 0 AS CHAR) = '2001foo'
```

The first line is doing the same thing as the current query. And that can take advantage of a suitable index.

The second condition is converting the same value to a numeric, then casting that back to character, and then comparing the result to the original. With the values shown here, it will evaluate to FALSE, and the query will not return any rows.

This will also not return a row if the string value has a leading space,  ' 2001'.  The second condition is going to evaluate as FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

When comparing an `INT` to a 'string', the string is converted to a number.

Converting a string to a number takes as many of the leading characters as it can and still be a number.  So `'2001character'` is treated as the number `2001`.

If you want non-numeric characters in `member_id`, make it `VARCHAR`.
If you want only numeric ids, then reject `'200.1character'`